# Regex to match a few specific 6 digit numbers (Indian pin codes)

Tags: regex, google-forms

I am using Google Forms to create an application form. Need to restrict submission for a few specific pin codes only. Here are some of the pin codes that I'm trying to limit it to.

```
560078 560070 560085 560069 560011 560080 560004 570070 560089 560060
```

First 4 digits are same in all the pin codes. I need to match the last two digits to the ones from a list. The list might end up being about 30, hence looking for a regex.

Which regex should I use for that?

Comment: regex is bad at matching number ranges. But if it's only a few, could use the regex OR `|` for the 2 digit list.  F.e. `^5600(?:70|78|11)$`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the exact ranges. The pattern `5600(04|11|[6-8]\d)` will match:

- `560004`
- `560011`
- all the numbers from  `560060` to `560089`
  It will need to be corrected according to the acceptable ranges.

It is suprising to see `570070` in the list when you note that the first 4 digits are always the same. Is it an error or an excpetion.